# How to make my local scroll offset work with this fixed header?

Tags: jquery, scroll, responsive-design, offset, zurb-foundation

So I have been designing this site with zurb foundation's responsive template for a few days... As a last minute decision I decided to make the header #header fixed... Everything works the same except the content slides under the header on each scroll event.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the offset work correctly?!?!

I am using the jQuery localscroll plugin like so

```
$.localScroll({hash:true, offset: {top: 65},duration: 1000,easing:'easeInOutExpo'});
```

I have tried changing the offset: {top:} paramater to both 60 & -60 but anything that I try gives me back a shaky animation at best :-/

SO... I thought maybe I can just leave the .js alone and fix it by shifting the panels down with css? or maybe the #main container?... But nope... Couldn't get that to work either?

So I am looking for a way to either fix the local scroll offset... OR... Shift everything down somehow to accomodate the #header?

Possible conflicting files here:

http://example.com/javascripts/foundation/jquery.offcanvas.js
http://example.com/js/main2.js 
http://example.com/index.php

Comment: other conflicting file is here: /javascripts/foundation/jquery.offcanvas.js

Comment: I don't really get what the problem is; the page looks fine to me

Comment: When you click any of the top menu items.... The page should scroll so that the title of the corresponding slide is just under the header... Currently it slides to where the titles are underneath the header

Comment: Well I can't see the scrolling code, but it seems like you should just scroll to wherever you are now minus the header's height

Comment: Please post the scrolling code

Comment: I posted the conflicting files in the question... Thanks for looking at it... I am still stuck... the content is sliding just under the 65px tall header when you click the items in the main navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by simply adding padding to the top of each slide... Not what I envisioned... But it works! :)

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution?

Comment: This is the best tip ever. Don't forget to set the bottom margin if you need to ensure the correctness of the spacing between your "sections": `section { padding-top: 67px; margin-bottom: -67px; }`

Answer (score 3):

the syntax for offset is:

`offset: -50`

not:

`offset {top:50}`

that may be the issue.

Comment: This comment is incorrect. localScroll inherits the options from the scrollTo plugin which, based on the developers documentation (https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) allows for either one/both of a top or left offset.

Comment: In the localScroll documentation they use the corrected version. Although localScroll is based off of scrollTo, it appears to have different syntax.

Comment: But I corrected my syntax and still couldn't get localScroll to work. I ended up switching to SmoothScroll, which is absolutely wonderful. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem, and couldn't get localScroll to work, even after fixing the syntax. I ended up switching to a different tool, [SmoothScroll]: https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll#readme

It's wonderful. Try it.